# How to remove (uninstall) all games from Kubuntu 12.04 using CLI?

Tags: command-line, uninstall, games, kde

I see that the list of installed games is rather long. If I remove them one by one it will take hours using commands such as:

```
sudo apt-get purge kbounce
```

There is a meta-package called kdegames, but removing it appeared to do nothing:

```
sudo apt-get purge kdegames
```

Can anyone help me with a command that will remove all KDE games (and related libraries, etc.) from my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a method posted by mjrich way back on 08-21-2005

http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/nix/distro/debian/deb14-PackageRelatedCommandsInstallation/ar01s04.html

I slightly modified that method to come up with this:

```
dpkg -l | grep game | awk '{ print $2 }' > outfile
dpkg-query -W --showformat '${Section}\t${Package}\n' | grep ^games | awk '{ print $2 }' >> outfile
apt-get --purge remove `cat outfile`
apt-get autoremove
rm outfile*
```

It appears to have worked. Before I accept this as the answer I will wait to see if someone comes up with a better method. Thanks.

Comment: If you use `>>` instead of `>` in the second command you could skip merging the two files